# Allow sellers to edit tier pricing

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice, edit, tiered-pricing

How would I add the ability for sellers to edit their product's tier pricing when editing that product?

I would like to add something like this (screenshot from the admin panel) to the frontend for sellers to be able to edit themselves. How would I go about doing this?

[image]